# Issue in plotting a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to do an analysis of news websites which compares how many articles each website has written about covid. I was successfully able to extract articles titles of news websites and also do a word search which tells how many of all the articles extracted had the word "COVID" in it. Now I want to represent the word search result in a bar graph , I used matplotlib, but I'm getting an error which I'm unable to understand. Please help.

Following is the code, (the last part  of the code is about the graph where I'm getting an error):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector
from newspaper import Article
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
URL=["https://www.timesnownews.com/coronavirus","https://www.indiatoday.in/coronavirus"]
Url_count = []
for url in URL:
    parser = 'html.parser'  
    resp = requests.get(url)
    http_encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
    html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(resp.content, is_html=True)
    encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, parser, from_encoding=encoding)
    
    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if "javascript" in link["href"]:
            continue
        links.append(link['href'])
            
    count = 0
     
            
    for link in links:
        try:
            article = Article(link)
            article.download()
            article.parse()
            print(article.title)
            if "COVID" in article.title or "coronavirus" in article.title or "Coronavirus"in article.title or "Covid-19" in article.title or "COVID-19" in article.title :
                    count += 1
    
        except:
            pass
    Url_count.append(count)
    
for url, count in zip(URL, Url_count):
    print("Site:", url, "Count:", count)
    # x-coordinates of left sides of bars  
    left = [URL]
    # heights of bars 
    height=[Url_count]
    # labels for bars 
    tick_label=['timesnow', 'India today']
    # plotting a bar chart 
    plt.bar(left, height, tick_label = tick_label, 
        width = 0.8, color = ['red', 'green']) 
    # naming the x-axis 
    plt.xlabel('News websites') 
    # naming the y-axis 
    plt.ylabel('Number of articles') 
    # plot title 
    plt.title('Media analysis') 
  
    # function to show the plot 
    plt.show()
```

Following is the error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2369                 try:
-> 2370                     left = x - width / 2
   2371                 except TypeError as e:

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U40'), dtype('<U40')) -> dtype('<U40')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-59393af79dcd> in <module>
     45     tick_label=['timesnow', 'India today']
     46     # plotting a bar chart
---> 47     plt.bar(left, height, tick_label = tick_label, 
     48         width = 0.8, color = ['red', 'green']) 
     49     # naming the x-axis

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2405         x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center',
   2406         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2407     return gca().bar(
   2408         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
   2409         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1563     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1564         if data is None:
-> 1565             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1566 
   1567         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2370                     left = x - width / 2
   2371                 except TypeError as e:
-> 2372                     raise TypeError(f'the dtypes of parameters x ({x.dtype}) '
   2373                                     f'and width ({width.dtype}) '
   2374                                     f'are incompatible') from e

TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (<U40) and width (float64) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the bar plot is incorrect. You don't need a for loop to plot multiple bars. you can give `plt.bar(x, y)` x and y where x is a list of coordinates of the bars, and y is the list of heights.
I recommend you check the documentation on the [barplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)

What would be nice especially if you're going to do this for a lot of websites is generate a list from the URL list with only the website name, so remove the "www." and the ".com/...." so you only need to give your program a list of urls and it'll do the job for you.

To solve your problem, replace the last for loop with the following code:

```
import numpy as np 

# make an array for the x-axis from the URL List 
nx = np.arange(len(URL)) 

labels = ['timessnownews', 'indiatoday']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_title('Media analysis')
ax.bar(nx, Url_count)
ax.set_xticks(nx)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of articles')
ax.set_xlabel('News Websites')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `left` parameter needs to be an array of the x axis values.  You're passing a list of strings.  And I'm not sure why you're doing this in a loop, when you're plotting the whole set every time.

Also, `height` needs to be a list of the bar heights, but you're make it a list of a list.  Remember, `Url_count` is already a list.